# How to add attachment using mailgun in dart with http?

Tags: http, dart, attachment, mailgun

Mailgun officially supports http but there is no official package for Dart, as of September 2020.  The email sends successfully but the attachment is missing.  Notice all of the failed attempts.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as foo;

// must be https for basic auth (un + pw)
const secureProtocol = 'https://';
const host = 'api.mailgun.net/v3/m.givenapp.com/messages';

// basic auth
const userApiKey = 'my api key here'; // pw
const un = 'api';

void main() async {
  //
  const path = 'bin/services/foo.baz.txt';
  var file = File(path);
  print(file.existsSync()); // looks good
  print(file.readAsStringSync()); // looks good
  var list = <String>[];
  list.add(file.readAsStringSync());
  var files = <File>[];
  files.add(file);
  //
  var body = <String, dynamic>{};
  body.putIfAbsent('from', () => 'John Smith <john.smith@example.com>');
  body.putIfAbsent('to', () => 'jane.doe@somehost.com');
  body.putIfAbsent('subject', () => 'test subject  ' + DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
  body.putIfAbsent('text', () => 'body text');

  // fixme
  body.putIfAbsent('attachment', () => '@$path'); // failed
  body.putIfAbsent('attachment', () => path); // failed
  //body.putIfAbsent('attachment', () => file); // failed
  //body.putIfAbsent('attachment', () => list); // failed
  //body.putIfAbsent('attachment', () => files); // failed
  body.putIfAbsent('attachment', () => file.readAsStringSync()); // failed
  //body.putIfAbsent('attachment', () => file.readAsBytesSync()); // failed

  final uri = '$secureProtocol$un:$userApiKey@$host';

  final response = await foo.post(uri, body: body);

  print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${response.body}');
}
```

I think I'm close.

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you linked say

> Important: You must use multipart/form-data encoding when sending attachments.

So you want to do a `MultipartRequest`, not just a normal post request.

This can be done roughly with the following code using the same http package you're already using.

```dart
var request = foo.MultipartRequest(
  'POST',
  Uri.parse('$secureProtocol$un:$userApiKey@$host')
);

var body = <String, dynamic>{};
body.putIfAbsent('from', () => 'John Smith <john.smith@example.com>');
body.putIfAbsent('to', () => 'jane.doe@somehost.com');
body.putIfAbsent('subject', () => 'test subject  ' + DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
body.putIfAbsent('text', () => 'body text');

request.fields = body;

request.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('attachment', path));

var response = await request.send();
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

Everything is done the same with adding the from, to, subject, and text fields, just adding it to the `fields` parameters of the `MultipartRequest`.

The headers were changed to indicate the correct type. A `MultipartFile` is create from the path and given the field name of `attachment`. This is added to the files part of the `MultipartRequest`.

The request is then sent and handled similarly to what you already had.

---

If you want to do this more easily you can try the [`mailgun` package](https://pub.dev/packages/mailgun), which does all this for you.

Comment: That was the most polite way to say, "RTFM".   This guy deserves a metal of honor.